# Clear screen before bang (!)

Tags: vim

I would appreciate if some one can figure how to clean screen when I do i.e.:

`:!git status`

It always show me the previous output, so if I repeat this task many times can confuse me because I see the history.

With an external keyboard usually I do `:!git status` + ctrl+K+enter but for unknown reason on my internal keyboard (macbook pro) didn't do the trick.

There is a best way to do that? Maybe in vimrc.

Thanks guys!

---

Finally I figure how we can do that with built-in terminal.app. Write `:!your command` then press CMD + K + ENTER and you see a clean screen!

Comment: Write a shell script to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't mind a little extra typing:

```
:!clear; git status
```

Comment: Yep It's what Im using right now, I can remap `!` to add always `clear` ? How? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What about using an external plugin for git? [fugitive](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) is a great one! Some [more](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) details and screencasts. It can show `git status` with `:Gstatus` (which you can map to some shortcut key...)

HTH

Comment: Yep, I know, I've also some of them, btw mine is an example I use also some other commands, launch daemons, test script etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to type

```
:!clear; git status
```

every time (I didn't) so maybe just a slightly better option is to go to your ~/.vimrc and add

```
command! -nargs=1 R :!clear && <args>
```

I chose "R" because I thought of the word "Run". It could be any uppercase letter you want or it could even be "Run". You would use it like"

```
:R git status
```

And then when you run it again, it will not show the previous Foo! in the terminal. I would say it is almost as easy to type "!". Just a thought!